# Comet Chat in GoDaddy Linux Dedicated Server?

Tags: comet, ajax-push

- I want to know if it's possible to make my own chat application with ajax push.
- And if it's, what is the easiest way to do it?

I know how to use javascript and make ajax calls but that's as far as I go. I can find tutorials myself but I can't tell whether the method is good or not so any links will be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

to use ajax push (comet), you must make a server that will keep concurrent connections.

You can really do anything look for echo servers in your favorite language. Java/C/C++.. I'd do this in Java since it can run on Linux as well.

You can use http://www.ape-project.org/ which seems to be done already all for you.. but seems complex.. I'd recommend starting from scratch with a echo server.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using Node.js as it is great at Comet/Ajax-push. Why is it great? Comet applications tend to be event driven and Node.js/javascript excels at these kinds of things.

However, if you prefer to do it in Java, Tomcat actually supports Comet as long as your servlet implements CometProcessor and you use NIO as your http connector. See http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/aio.html